# How to Open & Close multiple excel workbooks based on a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I need code to open and immediately close files 1 at time to prevent crashing. The object file paths start at A3 and continue downwards and can range in the hundreds. 
I only need it to open and close to run macro within each file that happen upon closing.

I have no idea where to even begin.

Comment: *"1 at time to prevent crashing"* - what is your current code that is causing the crashing?

Comment: I have no code. Can't find any that opens files based on cell value. I'm just concerned about opening 100 excel documents at once, causing my computer to crash.

Comment: `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Cells(i, 1).Value)`?

Comment: Loop through the cells, open 1 workbook, close it with `wb.Close True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimal example:

From row 3 to however many rows contain a value, open the workbook by setting it to `wb`, then close it with the optional parameter of `True` to save it.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Test()

    Dim i As Long, wb As Workbook

    For i = 3 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Cells(i, 1).Value)
        DoSomething wb
        wb.Close True
    Next i

End Sub

Private Sub DoSomething(ByVal wb As Workbook)
    'do stuff...
End Sub
```

Comment: Good edit, I was under the impression the workbooks had a `Workbook_Open()` event in them...

Comment: Re-reading the OP, I think you're right.

Comment: So amazingly close. I don't know how make it call a macro within the opened cell. The simple Call SendToMaster gets me run time error 10004

Comment: @Lupo You'll have to include the code for that macro here.

Comment: You guys are the absolute best, thanks.